# What is bootstrap calender and how to select a date from bootstrap calendar which is read only in selenium web driver using java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

i am not able to select a date from a calendar.I need to select a date automatically from the calendar.I am not able to inspect the calendar as the calendar is disappearing automatically when i click on calendar.Because of that i am not able to write the code in selenium.
This is the calendar which i am using in my application.
[image]

Comment: have you use sendKeys() for input field

Comment: yes.When i gave sendkeys in select date field value is passing but it is not proced further.

Comment: Can you post your code what you have tried?

Comment: use submit() after send keys or move to next element let's see

Comment: WebElement flight_date=d.findElement(By.xpath(rx.readdatafromexcel("configuration", 2,1)));
 mod.click(flight_date);

Comment: mod.sendkeys(flight_date, "2019-02-18");
 flight_date.submit();

Comment: i wrote this one.But it is not submitting.Did i do any wrong?

Comment: can you pass "02-18-2019" this might work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this.See if it helps.

```
WebElement ele2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='seldatetext']"));
ele2.sendKeys("18-Feb-2019");
ele2.submit();
```

Comment: it is not taking properly.

Comment: Once execution is over if i do any action after it is loading for next field.

Comment: did you use ```ele2.submit();``` or ```ele2.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);``` after that?

Comment: See any difference you have.

Comment: I think because of date string you might getting problem.I have changed the date string in my code.Now please try.